# How to integrate app with payment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, payment

I want to make screen like this to make checkout and payment process:

[image]

I can't understand how it will be, and what should i use ,are there some `libraries`
how can i implement this in my APP.

Comment: I don't know much about payments, but I do know it is difficult to setup payment with a credit card company. There is no library to do it and you need to contact various financial institutions to get authorized (I don't really know the process). Maybe consider going through a company that offers online payments such as Paypal where your customers will be redirected to Paypal's service to actually submit their credit card information.

Comment: Thank you, so i'll try with `paypal`

Comment: Please note, that Google have made updates to their user policies, regarding payments. 3rd party payment providers are advise against and, in some cases, not entirely permitted. If you want to keep it on the easy and safe side, I recommend you use the payments provided by Google.

Comment: what about to use `PayPal REST API` ?
@DanailAlexiev

Comment: It's definitely an option. Although, I would still choose the In App Payment mechanisms, provided by Google. They take away a lot of the complexity for you, Android users are familiar with them and they are more "native" in a way. Please, bear in mind that my opinion is purely subjective.